# Handle missing data

Tags: imputation

I was wondering how people typically handle missing data problems? 
I read some articles about imputing missing data, where basically the idea is to replace the missing data by some value calculated in some way.

For example, suppose I have a table with some missing cells, and I want to fill these cells using some imputation technique. I image I should first use some carefully chosen function `f` and apply `f` on some existing data in the table to compute the value to replace a specific missing value. Is this true?

Comment: Yes. What you describe is called [interpolation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interpolation).

Comment: @PM77-1 Is it always easy to find the existing data that are used to estimate the missing value? Can I do this manually or is it better to write a little program in the case where there might be many missing values? Are there tools that can fully automate this process with requiring me to write programs?

Comment: There are tons of books written on the subject.  It's not possible to discuss it in Q&A format here.